# data type conversion extracting user defined tags as columns using Openstreetmap data

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

we have an ,osm data in which we have used some tags that we defined ourselves like, age, roof_type, roof_slope . we want to convert this file to shapefile, in which the roof_type tag appears as a column name and its values  as attributes.

we have tried:

**QGIS:** install plugin, only creates column of 7 tags, others are grouped into one column called tags

**OSM2GIS:** online tools, selects area on map, has many tags, but not user defined ones

**Geoconverter:** online tools, input a supported file and it will export a supported file, but not user defined ones

**OSMembrane:** still learning, frontend for Osmosis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QuantumGIS 2.0.

process is here [How do I load OSM vector data in QGIS 2.x?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73238/how-do-i-load-osm-vector-data-in-qgis-2-0/73334#73334)

Answer (score 1):

Osm2pgsql allows you to add as many tags for columns in the default.style file as you like. The result is stored in a postgis database, and can be extracted and visualized from there with Quantum Gis.

Comment: it is a command line tool, is there any frontend, wrapper for it, like jar or exe file. I have to teach it to others and they are not programmers.

Comment: There is no gui for it. If you put the command line in a bat file, you can edit it with an editor, save and double-click it. If it runs, you don't have to change it anymore.