# OpenstreetMap losing information

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, import

I successfully created a shapefile from OpenStreetMap with the OpenStreetMap tool in QGIS 2.2. When I try to create a polyline layer, it says that there are 8000 values in the db file for the property highway, but after the import I have only 6000 in the attribute list.

The problem is that I don't have all streets available for a given city and because of that I am unable to draw parcels where the streets are their borders. Is that problem normal or am I missing something?

Comment: Try if you can get more streets by letting GDAL to open the data. Use Add vector layer - [name of your .osm or .pbf file].

Comment: In my experience, the data download is not hundred percent reliable. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73238/how-do-i-load-osm-vector-data-in-qgis-2-x/101746#101746 for more options of using OSM data in QGIS 2.x