# Why I cannot export OSM map as a .pdf/.jpeg in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, print-composer, mac

I have installed on my Mac OSX 10.9.5 the version QGIS 2.4.

My problem is that I cannot export any OpenStreetMap with the Composer and I do not understand why. The thing is that I imported the OSM map with the OpenLayers plugin... everything normal, OK. Then I started to edit some vectors... and then I tried to export the map with the Composer... but it just does not work! I can load everything there, but when I press the export buttons, then the window becomes blank. And it creates a new .pdf for example but with 0 bytes...

Does anyone have an idea about what I did wrong, or what is wrong? I may have missed some key details that I did not know that should be done...but still...Is there any chance to have the background of the OSM map exported somehow like .pdf? What I can do?

Or better, another question, is it even possible to export the OSM imported with OpenLayers Plugin with the Composer?... or I should download the data on my computer first?

Comment: I don't encourage you to download the data yourself. Styling in QGIS is a very time-consuming work, and the project gets slow on every zoom if you have a larger area. It's the benefit of prerendered tiles that you have fast access to the map background. If you just need some special POI's from OSM, downloading is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the OpenLayers plugin if you want to print. It does not work, see: [Why do OpenLayers plugin layers appear shifted in QGIS print composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42044/why-do-openlayers-plugin-layers-appear-shifted-in-qgis-print-composer)

Use QuickMapServices plugin instead or download the data - but then you have to style it yourself, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/101746/187