# QGIS unable to export OSM topology to SpatiaLite

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, export

QGIS 2.18.2
I am downlaoding OSM data for a QGIS project.
The first 2 steps work fine: Vector/OpenStreetMap/Download data and Import topology from XML.
However when I try to execute step 3 - Export topology to SpatiaLite - I get an error "Failed to export OSM data: Unable to create table.  Duplicate column name FIXME."  The error occurs for all 3 export types, point, line and polygon.

Comment: Can you add the bounding box where you downloaded the data to reproduce the error?

Comment: What tags are you trying to save?

Comment: does [this answer help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164075/55203)? I sometimes find there are two or more (case-sensitive) spellings of 'fixme'. If you uncheck one of them the error will go away (but you may lose some of the 'fixme' data)

Comment: If the raw .osm file is not too big, you can search&replace any `FIXME` with `fixme` before step 2 to avoid data loss.

Comment: Under Exported Tags I clicked on 'Load from DB' and then 'Select All'.  I think this was the cause of the problem.  If I select only one tag, all goes well.  The case FIXME in the error message was all upper. Lack of understanding of what was happening I suspect was my main problem.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I too experienced the same problem. The error is caused if two(or more) data columns in the attribute tables have the same name. Resolve it by loading them in separately and editing the and later merge them.
Here's an example of me using an osm data set the entries FIXme and fixme are the same and have to be edited separately[image: image showing the two data points to be loaded in the database]

Hope this helps and happy GIS

edit: other common stuff you may find may be Name/Notes etc
So go through everything