# OSM data in QGIS: buildings have gaps (open and closed lines)

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I'm trying to show all buildings of a certain region in Switzerland using the OSM integration tools for QGIS. Using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73334/62121), I've downloaded and imported data to my project, choosing the attributes "building", "source" and some other, cf. screenshot below:

[image: Options for the OSM exportation to Spatialite].

The tags are basically the same whether I chose polylines or polygons under "export type". However, when importing them, I get different results: for the polygons, a part of the buildings are simply missing, and I can get their contours when I import the polylines, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image: Polylines and polygons of OSM data].

I would like to have all buildings as polygons, and not as open lines, and am not sure if this can even be achieved. I have read through most similar forum articles but haven't found a reply concerning this very issue.

Comment: Look the area up in a web OSM editor directly, just to make sure the problem isn't present in the original data.

Comment: Missing buildings seem to be created as multipolygon relations into OSM. See for example http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/452859. Perhaps this tool can't resolve relations. You can try to open OSM data through the GDAL OSM driver by using Add vector layer.

Comment: Might be related to these open bug reports: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8878 and https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12727

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user30184 - I've tried importing it as a vector layer - but then, I don't have the attributes of the object as separate columns, so I can't filter the OSM map by a particular attribute, such as "building"

Comment: You must read http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html and find the osmconf.ini file from your system and edit it to import the attributes which you need for filtering.

Comment: That sounds uncomfortable - but I see what this should do. This is however not a solution for an average QGIS user with limited time.