# How to view and query raw OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap

I have downloaded a xml OSM file, but I would like to query by mouse possition a way Id, nodes Id, etc...

I only need to view it.

I'm exploring OpenTripPlanner, to be able to calculate routes with it I have my streets graph using a OSM file. I also intend to update ways speed limits using traffic data. I have the traffic data, and know it's position, now I need to find out the way Id at that position to be able to match it (so routing takes that into account).

I have QGis, but I have only been able to load all the nodes in the file, but not the complete graph (ways, etc...) and don't know how to query it (I need something similar to WFS).

Which is the more convenient way?, I'm using QGis but if there is a better tool feel free to mention it.

---

After a comment I tried loading the OSM file using `layer` > àdd layer`>`add vector layer` I have now loaded the data and I'm querying it in QGis, but how can I view the nodes in a way?

For example, I'm examining the way with id = `172550740`, but how can I view the nodes (specially start and end nodes)?

Comment: Have you added the data to Qgis with `Add Vector layer`? It should add all features in the file.

Comment: I followed the accepted answer on this question [http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/73238/20614], but that did not work for me. However following this answer [http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/86259/20614] on the same question it worked, which is the same as @AndreJ pointed out. Thanks for that.

Comment: It is common practice here to ask just one question per topic, which has been answewered in the linked question already. I suggest to start a new question about the node. You can extract nodes of any line feature, but I guess you want the openstreetmap node id, and adjacent ways. You have to build a spatial database (postgis or spatialite) to save those informations from raw OSM data as well.