# Update driving way speed in open trip planner and how to [easily] obtain the needed ids?

Tags: openstreetmap, opentripplanner

I'm trying to update the driving way speed limits in OTP. I have seen how opentraffic data graph updater does it, and I have created a custom one that reads from a very simple Json (just the 4 mandatory fields, wayId, startNodeId, endNodeId and average traffic speed ).

I have access to road devices that calculate the average speed in a given point which, in order to give it to OTP, I need to associate with a way, start node and end nodes ids.

To do that I have tried using [QGis to load the OSM file data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/201307/20614), now I can select the way, and know the wayId. But how can I view its nodes? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a complex answer as everything depends on your data source. Is it already linked to OSM, a set of speed vector, zones...? You can have a look at the **[OpenTraffic](https://github.com/opentraffic)** projects (architecture and  to see an example on how a GPS point source can be mapped to OSM IDs.

Another issue to keep in mind is that OSM data evolves in time (ways and nodes gets created, updated, deleted) and any mapping may become invalidated at some point.

Comment: I have seen opentraffic but haven't yet dig into it. My data is not directly linked to OSM, that's exactly what I want to do. I know where the measurement points are located, so I would like to query 'nearby' features and extract the 3 ids needed (at first by hand to check results). I'm using a local extract of OSM data so IDs won't change unless is desired. But I start to think that it is the right moment to look into opentraffic in depth.

Comment: I definitely need to look into opentraffic, because OTP splits OSM ways into different edges with no ids ( id = 0 ), so knowing the OSM way, start node and end node is not sufficient.